# Table of contents with roman, arabic, and no page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I am trying to create a customized table of contents with the following 
form.  I have been looking at a number of sources but still having a hard 
time getting it to work adequately.  Right before the abstract there is a 
title page that should not be considered in the table of contents. There is 
an appendix at the end, that should not have a page number.

The table of contents should look like this:

```
                                   Table of Contents

            Abstract............................................ ii
            Acknowledgement. ................................... iii
            Table of Contents................................... iv
            Tables.............................................. v
            Figures............................................. vi
            1.0 Introduction ................................... 1
                    1.1 Background.............................. 2
                    1.1 Objectives.............................. 3
            2.0 Review.......................................... 4
                    2.1 xxxxxxxxxx.............................. 5
                    2.2 yyyyyyyyyy.............................. 6
            3.0 Conclusion...................................... 7
            4.0 References...................................... 8
            CODE................................................ 9
            APPENDIX
```

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: Should the chapter numbering 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,... also be maintained in the document or is it just for the ToC?

Comment: What is the "title that should not be considered"? Sounds like a phrase from [Harry Potter: "He who must not be named"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Voldemort). `:)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using the `tocloft` package and the `book` document class:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\listtablename{Tables}
  \renewcommand\listfigurename{Figures}
  \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
}

% Centered title for ToC, LoF, LoT
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}

% Leaders for chapter entries
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}

% Add space to account for new chapter numbering schema
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{3em}
\renewcommand\cftsecindent{3em}

% Redefine representation for chapter (and section) counters
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.0}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Background}
\section{Objectives}
\chapter{Review}
\section{Test Section}
\section{AnotherTest Section}

\backmatter
\chapter{CODE}

\chapter*{APPENDIX}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{APPENDIX}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for including the ToC in the ToC, as specified by the OP. :-)

Comment: @lockstep: it's such a senseless (and ugly) practice, but some institutions require it as part of their format for theses.

Answer (score 5):

Here' s an example using the `book` class. `\frontmatter` causes Roman, `\mainmatter` arabic page numbering. For the appendix, I switch off page numbering manually with `\pagenumbering{gobble}` and add an unnmumbered `\part`.

EDIT: Added changed numbering scheme (plus correction of ToC indents).

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{1.5em}{2.3em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\l@section}{{1.5em}{2.3em}}{{2.3em}{2.3em}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Acknowledgement}

\mainmatter

\chapter{bla}

\section{blubb}

\chapter{foo}

\cleardoublepage
\appendix
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\part*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}

\chapter{bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between `\pagenumbering{empty}` and `\pagenumbering{gobble}`? Just curious.

Comment: Well, `\pagenumbering{empty}` results in an error. You were thinking of `\pagestyle{empty}`, weren't you? ;-)

Comment: Yes, I was. :-)