# Chapter Heading Arabic but Roman Numeral in Table of Contents (TOC)

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

Someone provided me the following class called `existingclass.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
\ProvidesClass{existingclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{}
\setlength{\parindent}{.3in}

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  right = 1in,
  left = 1.5in,
  top = 1in,
  bottom = 1in
}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS} 
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{
    {
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \centering
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \bfseries CHAPTER \thechapter
            \par\nobreak
            \vskip 20\p@    
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
    }
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
    {
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \centering
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
    }
}
```

and is loaded to the following tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{existingclass}

\begin{document}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    \tableofcontents    
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

having inserted the following (minimal) `chapter1.tex`:

```
\chapter{THE PROBLEM}
```

When you run this code, it will output the following:

[image]
[image]

**MY QUESTION:** *How do I change the chapter (header) numbering found in the document to Arabic while retaining the chapter sectioning in the TOC (Table of Contents) to Roman Numerals?*

I looked for the following similar problems:

[Chapter Roman in tableofcontents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196218/chapter-roman-in-tableofcontents)

[Roman number in chapter header but not in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370275/roman-number-in-chapter-header-but-not-in-toc)

[Roman numerals for table of contents, arabic for main text in footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108273/roman-numerals-for-table-of-contents-arabic-for-main-text-in-footer)

[Change number after chapter in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231302/change-number-after-chapter-in-table-of-contents?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Chapter headings and table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495638/chapter-headings-and-table-of-contents)

[Roman Numerals in ToC : Error in \settowidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347041/roman-numerals-in-toc-error-in-settowidth)

[Table of contents with roman, arabic, and no page numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37940/table-of-contents-with-roman-arabic-and-no-page-numbers)

[Page numbering with a mixed Roman numeral-Arabic numeral format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38565/page-numbering-with-a-mixed-roman-numeral-arabic-numeral-format)

[Roman numbering of pages on ToC, but arabic on document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262548/roman-numbering-of-pages-on-toc-but-arabic-on-document)

[Page numbering resets after table of contents (roman/arabic)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194976/page-numbering-resets-after-table-of-contents-roman-arabic)

but none, so far, answered my question

P.S.: I am not an expert in pure TeX codes. :)

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to share the class and/or change its name?

Comment: @Johannes_B Any particular reason to think not?

Comment: `\thechapter` -> `\arabic{chapter}`? Are you expert in impure TeX codes? They're definitely the best kind ;).

Comment: @cfr License stuff.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, but we don't routinely ask this about class files, so why this one? Or would you ask this about any code an OP included which the OP wanted to adapt?

Comment: @cfr I *do* ask it on class files. I am a bit weird about licenses.

Comment: @Johannes_B Fair enough. I'm a bit weird about licences myself (even though I spell them differently). However, I seriously doubt that the code included in this question is copyrightable. That said, I'm certainly no lawyer.

Comment: @cfr, where do I put code `\thechapter -> \arabic{chapter}`?

Comment: @Johannes_B, it's ok. It's actually really a very reducted form of the original and anonymized it as `existingclass.cls` (not the original name)

Comment: We cannot process your file as we have no idea what `existingclass` is. Please provide an MWE (from `documentclass...` to `\end{document}` that we can compile. (I have a feeling that the `tocloft` package may help you, but ...

Comment: After the word `CHAPTER`? But it is just a guess. Without a proper example, that's all anybody can do here.